# Printing RTF Text in PDFLib 9 Table Cell

Tags: perl, pdf, pdflib

I am using Perl and PDFLib 9 to dynamically create a PDF document. I read some data from a DB and print a table with the data onto the PDF. One field in my DB contains RTF text. How can i print RTF text in a PDFLib table cell? I can't find any example in the PDFLib cookbook.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25710250/4050592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can **not** use RTF text for PDFlib textflow/table cells. So you have to parse your RTF text and "translate" this into textflow notation. Afterwards you can format text within a multiline text by using inline options within create_textflow() or by calling multiple add_textflow() calls.